# uinavigationbar uiappearance in popover bartintcolor not working

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uiappearance

I uses `UIAppearance` to set the bartint color for my `UINavigationBar`, this works fine except for navigation bars in popovers, am I missing something here?

the following line is in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [[UIImage imagewithcolor:[UIColor redColor]] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope this wil work